# Mac OS Catalina does not shutdown correctly if "rails server" is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, macos-catalina, ruby-on-rails-6

I've been using `rails server` with Rails 6.0.1 on Mac OS Catalina. I've noticed that if start the server (whether using Puma or unicorn), and shut it down, and try to shut down the computer, it just hangs until Apple's watchdog forcefully shuts down the system. Upon the next bootup, I always get the same crash report.

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f8ef9daae): watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd in 187 seconds (21 totalcheckins since monitoring last enabled), shutdown in progress
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff83b7473c40 : 0xffffff800e539a3b
0xffffff83b7473c90 : 0xffffff800e670fe5
0xffffff83b7473cd0 : 0xffffff800e662a5e
0xffffff83b7473d20 : 0xffffff800e4e0a40
0xffffff83b7473d40 : 0xffffff800e539127
0xffffff83b7473e40 : 0xffffff800e53950b
0xffffff83b7473e90 : 0xffffff800ecd1875
0xffffff83b7473f00 : 0xffffff7f8ef9daae
0xffffff83b7473f10 : 0xffffff7f8ef9d472
0xffffff83b7473f50 : 0xffffff7f8efb2e76
0xffffff83b7473fa0 : 0xffffff800e4e013e
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[AA44EEB8-57FA-3CAC-9105-C7AB21900B9A]@0xffffff7f8ef9c000->0xffffff7f8efa4fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[6DA4BDC6-9C64-34B3-A60E-D345D2DC2D5F]@0xffffff7f8efa5000->0xffffff7f8efc3fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.watchdog(1)[AA44EEB8-57FA-3CAC-9105-C7AB21900B9A]@0xffffff7f8ef9c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4A40B298-87E0-373E-84A9-9A2227924F8F]@0xffffff7f8ef07000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AA7C7A4F-9F5D-3533-9E78-177C3B6A72BF]@0xffffff7f8ef10000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19B88

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64
```

Has anyone else seen this problem and how did you go about fixing it? My guess is the `rails server` leaves some processes running even after it's shut down via Ctrl-C that's preventing the OS from shutting down correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a professional method, but...

- open a terminal (privileged if at all possible)
- take a snapshot using "ps" ("ps awxu" I seem to remember) of the running processes
- start the Rails server
- tinker a bit
- now *stop* the server
- take another snapshot

I fully expect some low-level background process to have been left running and not listening to shutdown signals. MacOS shutdown process is maybe too well-behaved and polite for its own good.

Should this be the case, get the PID or name of the process(es) and try pkilling it with HUP, TERM, and finally KILL signals. You can get a good idea of where those processes started from by checking their image path (be careful not to kill innocent processes).

Wait some time to be sure that pkilling the process didn't leave the system in an unstable state, then try shutting down the machine and see how it went.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common Catalina issue, and Apple clearly doesn't care about it. You can see [this stackexchange thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372183/catalina-crashing-at-shutdown-with-this-error), and [Apple forum discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250853017).

So far, there's no fix available, but resetting SMC/NVRAM can give You a few proper shutdowns.

Comment: but this seems to happen if I use rails c. If I don't, then I can shut down correctly.

Comment: This happens with multiple backgorund processes, in my case it was PostgreSQL and SteelSeries mouse driver. There's probably some process left alive after You start Rails, that causes the system watchogd to wait 3 minutes before shutdown

Answer (score 0):

One way to not being impacted by this issue is to use [Docker](https://www.docker.com) and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

I know it doesn't solve your root issue, but with Docker you're OS agnostic so that you can work on any OSes and still your project works if you can [install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/). You'll also survive OS upgrades.

Docker is now very common and popular so you can have a lot of help from the community, there are plenty of blog articles explaining how to containerise a Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this problem .

This problem is about `Catalina` support for `Graphic Processing Unit`

If you are using the `NVIDIA` Graphic chip , `Catalina` is no problem,

but there will be problems if you are using `AMD` in `Catalina`
Especially the 2015 `macbook pro`

Many APP provider are already compatible with this issue,

but Apple company has not responded .

For users this is an issue for Apple .